# Environment Variable setup for plugin "Gradle for Java"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

We use "Gradle for Java" plugin in VSCode to list down all the Gradle tasks in our Project. The main gradle file uses multiple environment variables like below,

```
providers.environmentVariable(DBPASSWORD).get()
```

Beacuse of this, the plugin does not list any of the gradle tasks in it. We have to manually hard code the value in these places and then refresh the gradle view to get the tasks list.

Is there any way in VSCode to setup environment variable for the Gradle plugin? I tried setting up Launch file for Java and that did not work